# VB Regex: String between X and Y where there are many Xs inside the text

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, between

So lets say we have the following text in VB:

"ABC X ABC X ABC Y ABC X ABC X ABC Y ABC X"

I want to be able to extract only the following occurrence: X ABC Y

I have tried this pattern: X(.*?)Y

But unfortunately it returns the whole thing starting from the first X:

"X ABC X ABC Y"

I would need to get the string between the last X before the Y and the Y.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negated character class.

```
X([^X]*)Y
```

OR

```
X(?:(?!\bX\b).)*Y
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jW6cF9/1)

Your regex `X(.*?)Y` matches the first `X` and the following characters upto the next Y. Once it finds a match then it tries to match the next X and all the characters upto the next Y.